# Cursor flickers with xrandr scaling

Tags: fedora, x11, xrandr, multi-monitor

Unhappy with the unreasonably large text on my 1920x1080 external screen connected to a laptop with a 3200x1800 display in Fedora 24, I tried rescaling the external screen by using:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 7040x2160 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 3840x0
```

This has the desired effect, but it causes the cursor to flicker when I move the mouse on the laptop screen. The cursor does not flicker when it is on the external screen. Flickering stops when I revert to 1x1 scaling on the external screen:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --scale 1x1 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 4120x1800 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 1920x0
```

How can I stop this flickering?

Comment: Possibly related to a bug in the modesetting driver.[See here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101225).

Answer (score 18):

[This workaround helped me](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7j2jzn/kde_multidpi_xrandrkrandr_experiences/dr3nosj/). What I do now is after performing a xrandr scale, I run an extra command which stops the mouse flicker.

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --output HDMI-2 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1  # Simpler oneliner scaling
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999  # Stop flicker
```

Comment: This is also an [open issue for xserver](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/70).

Comment: running `xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999` works but it slows down display reactions. You can see that when watching some fast video on youtube.

Comment: I agree. Using Wayland or the Intel driver on X is a better solution as of now.

Comment: That was immediately and impressively effective. Good job.

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact problem after using scaling with xrandr although with a slightly different setup. Strangely, what helped was the first section on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Xorg_configuration . Namely,

"However, to take advantage of some driver options, you will need to create a Xorg configuration file similar to the one below:"

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

That is probably only relevant if you're running on Intel graphics (and not on a dedicated gpu)

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu, however the relevant file to create is /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

Comment: This worked fine for me in ubuntu 18.04 (unity)

Comment: Works perfectly, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by creating said content in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf on a Macbook pro.  Note that you have to log out and back in again for the change to take effect.

Comment: `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` worked on Fedora 31. BTW the file content starts from `Section...`.

Comment: Tested and worked for me with Ubuntu 19.10 running on a Dell Precision 7510 with dual Nvidia and Intel graphics when only the Intel graphics is used.

Comment: Fixed issues on Linux Mint 20 as well. (Ubuntu 20.04 base)
The config file path was same as in Ubuntu mentioned above by Simon D. Thanks!

Comment: Started flickering for me after I attached an external USB monitor (wacom tablet), wouldn't stop after disconnecting it and rebooting. Doing this helped instantly.

Answer (score 2):

On a MacBook Pro with resolution of 2560x1600 and a Samsung TV with the resolution of 1680x1050 I found the following command useful:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --scale 0.9999x0.9999 --output HDMI-2 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1
```

I found it via reading [arch-linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Side_display) and the 0.9999x0.9999 scaling solution in answers on this page.